# why are assignments in conditions bad?

Tags: php, coding-style

I am using NetBeans for PHP 6.5.

In my code I frequently use the following type of command:

```
if (($row = $db->get_row($sql))) {
        return $row->folder;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Netbeans tells me that I should not be using assignments in the IF statement.

Why ?

Comment: I would have thought that the double parenthesis (the parenthesis around the assignment) should indicate that the assignment is intentional. Some compilers suppress the warning in this case I think.

Comment: Check out mark's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2576969/560287

Comment: Switch off that warning, replace with test driven development. ;)  The difference in behaviour between `=` and `==` is so big your tests should fail. (unlike `==` vs `===` - I'd like my IDE to warn about that, preferably)

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski This is nothing to do with confusing = and  ==. This is to do with assignments in conditions. eg should it put '$row = $db->get_row($sql)' on a previous line.

Comment: Others have already answered that the warning against = in a condition expression is everything to do with confusing = and ==.  I was just saying that with adequate testing, you will not even need the warnings, because such mistakes are drastic, testing will find them.  So if you find it tedious to use 2 statements instead of 1, ignore the warning, and continue to write code as in your example.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

They are not bad, but they can lead to dangerous mistakes.

In c like languages, where an assignment is an expression, (to support for example a=b=c=1;) a common error is:

```
if (a = 1) { .. }
```

But you wanted to have

```
if (a == 1) { .. }
```

Some developers have learned to type

```
if (1 == a) { .. }
```

To create an error if one '=' is forgotten. But I think that it does not improve the readability.

However modern compilers, give a warning if you write

```
if (a = 1) { .. }
```

which I think is a better solution. In that case you are forced to check if it was what you really meant.

Comment: I believe wrapping the assignment in the if with its own parentheses should tell the compiler the coder knows what he's doing, and he shouldn't be warned.

Comment: @strager I still consider this a bad practice because it doesn't really help readability if you assign something in an if clause. You do two things in one command, that can lead to misunderstandings and should be avoided.

Comment: @strager I've made that exact typo several times before and had the compiler catch me on it which saved could save hours debugging depending on when the side effects would have manifested (i.e. whether a compile time error vs showing incorrect data to the user somewhere down the line)

Comment: Very Bad!  if (a=1 or b=1)...  No way to know if the 2nd assignment executed.

Comment: For most languages you really should use strict comparison (===) and explicit casting if necessary, so it's even harder to miss. If you really want to avoid typos like this, should you also avoid using bitwise AND (&) in assignments? (And the list could go on...)

Answer (score 7):

It's probably trying to help you avoid the dreaded typo:

> ```
> if(a = b)
>    //logic error
> ```

Although I would expect an enviroment smart enough to warn you about that, to also be smart enough to have "oh, don't worry about that case" conditions.

Answer (score 6):

Conditionals often include short circuit operators.  So, given this example:

```
if ( a=func(x) && b=func(y) )
{
  // do this
}
```

It may not be immediately obvious, but the second assignment would only occur if the first returned `>0`, and if `func(y)` had other side effects that you were expecting, they would not happen either.

In short, if you know what you are doing and understand the side effects, then there is nothing wrong with it.  However, you must consider the possibility that someone else may be maintaining your code when you're gone and they might not be as experienced as you.

Also, future maintainers may think you intended the following:

```
if ( a==func(x) && b==func(y) ) ...
```

If they "fix" your code, they actually break it.

Comment: I would argue that this *should* be immediately obvious to any programmer worth his salt.  Maybe I am too harsh.

Comment: Yeah, but when you are debugging, things like that can "Blend In" and not immediately jump out, hence the arguments for breaking out the assignment operations.

Comment: @Kip yeah i agree with you 100%.  the problem is not all programmers are worth their salt.  we owe it to our customers to create maintainable software.  it is impossible to make software that is maintainable by the lowest common denominator of developer, but we can at least make some concessions.

Comment: You still can make it more readable: `result = func(x) && b=func(y); if(result)` ...

Answer (score 2):

In languages that allways return a value on assignments it's not *bad* (I think it's quite common in functional languages), but (as others allready have said while I typed this) it should usually be avoided since you or someone else might mistake it for a comparison. The compiler should usually warn about it, but it can be ignored if you're sure what you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

how would a code look like if you do not assign the $row value in the loop condition
this would be much more complicated i think...
although not that good to read for some maintainers, no?
well you can do it like

```
$next = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
do{
...
...
...

$next = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or break;
}while ($next)
```

Comment: This is surely more readable: [Sorry, no newlines in comments AFAIK]. `while(true) { $next = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); if ( ! $next ) { break; } /* body here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

I use them all the time, with loops (not sure why that would make a difference), like:

```
$counter = 0;
while( $getWhateverDataObj = mysql_fetch_object( $sqlResult )) {
   $getWhateverObj->firstName[$counter] = $getWhateverDataObj->firstName;
   $getWhateverObj->lastName[$counter]  = $getWhateverDataObj->lastName;
   $counter++;
}
```

And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In you're example, `if (($row = $db->get_row($sql))) {` is fine because of the extra parenthesises you used makes it clear that you intended to type `==` instead of `=`.

However, I would consider `if ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {` a mistake. It looks like a typo (`=` instead of `==`).

`Netbeans` is throwing an error because typing a single `=` in a condition is a very common typo. Another developer (or yourself a few months later) could assume it's a typo and introduce a bug into your code. I would of thought it would be smart enough to not throw a warning when extra parenthesis but guess not.