# Zend Warning Assignment

Tags: php

Zend is telling me i have an assignment in condition line 279, I'm not sure if this will be a issue later.

```
// Get position of delimiters
        $pos = [];
        foreach ($delims as $delim) {
            if ($p = strpos($this->data, $delim, min($this->index, $this->length))) {
                $pos[] = $p;
            }
        }
```

this is line 279

```
if ($p = strpos($this->data, $delim, min($this->index, $this->length))) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630035/zend-studio-reports-warning-assignment-in-condition-is-this-so-bad), this might work:

```
if (($p = strpos($this->data, $delim, min($this->index, $this->length))) != false)
```

Reason(from my understanding):

This will convert it as a conditional statement and eliminates chance of being an assignment. Hence, warning is resolved.

Comment: pseudoAJ thank you is there any specific reason it is a warning?

Comment: Edited my answer with plausible reason.