# Any problems with this technique to assign and check in PHP?

Tags: php, shorthand

Assignment and simple conditional:

```
$tacos = buy_taco( 3 );
if ( $tacos ) {
    eat_lunch( $tacos );
}
```

Does this shorthand approach have a name?

Any drawbacks or gotchas?

```
if ( $tacos = buy_taco( 3 ) ) {
    eat_lunch( $tacos );
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630035/zend-studio-reports-warning-assignment-in-condition-is-this-so-bad

Comment: The first way is better. It's clearer. If I see one equal sign in an if statement, alarms go off.

Comment: `$tacos` is always true, no need to test. `eat_lunch()` will be called even if the food truck is out of tacos, it'll just be burritos instead.