# PHP/Mysql-- Find Duplicate email but something wrong in my code

Tags: php, mysql

Check if the email is already exist..

```
$query="SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email='".$Email."'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("email cannot be added".mysql_error());
    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        die(" Sorry that user " .$email. " already exists ! <br>");
        }
```

Just give me simple program please

Comment: `if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))` this is always true...

Comment: @Rufinus ...except when there are no more rows to fetch, when it's `false`

Comment: I think the only problem with your program is that you're using `$Email` when it should be `$email`. The logic is correct, you just have a typo.

Comment: mike: nope, what you mean is something like `if(($row=mysql_fetch_array()))` $row = is just an assignment, the assignment is always true, no matter what mysql_fetch_array returns.

Comment: @rufinus - the assignment operator returns the value that has been assigned. So if `mysql_fetch_array()` returns false, then the assignment operator will return false.

Comment: conditonal assignments are very bad coding style... every better IDE warns about this bullsh1t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317259/why-are-assignments-in-conditions-bad

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false) {
    die("Sorry that user " . $email . " already exists ! <br>");
}
```

You should also know, that PHP variables are case sensitive, so using `$Email` and `$email` will fail, if one of them isn't defined.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his `if` statement, the strict comparison isn't needed. This isn't `strpos()`.

Comment: I never said, that his `if` statement is wrong? However, strict comparsion may be unnecessary, but also not wrong.

Comment: If you want to suggest a better way to write something, make it clear that this is what you're doing. Otherwise, it seems like you're saying this is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with `mysql_num_rows`

```
$query="SELECT email FROM user_info WHERE email='".$email."'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("email cannot be added".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    die(" Sorry that user " .$email. " already exists ! <br>");
}
```