# MySQL/PHP check for duplicate before INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check for an existing entry in MySQL before executing the INSERT statement.  If the user enters a name already in the database (field is set to unique) then they should be prompted to re-enter the name.

The problem I'm having is that if the new entry matches a record in any form then the error message displays and no INSERT happens.

For example, if the user enters DUMMY_NEW and there is a record DUMMY_OLD they aren't able to add the record even though DUMMY_NEW does not exist in the table.

I've searched and tried other answers already but can't seem to get this to work.

Code with extraneous bits removed for clarity:

```
//Create connection to database using mysqli
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

//Set variables according to user input on previous form
$Server_Name = $_POST['Server_Name'];

//Check for duplicate server name - if exists inform user else run INSERT ($stmt)
$checkdup = "SELECT * FROM dcr_table WHERE SERVER_NAME = '".$Server_Name."'";
$dupresult = $conn->query($checkdup);

if($dupresult = 1)
{
        print "<br>Error! <p></p>";
        echo "" . $Server_Name . " already exists in the DCR";
        print "<p></p>Please check the Server Name and try again";
}
else {


//Define the INSERT statement
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO dcr_master (Server_Name, Description,..., ... , ... )";

//Execute the INSERT statement
    $conn->query($stmt);

//Success and return new id
    echo "<br><p></p>Record Added!<p></p>";
    echo "New id: " . mysqli_insert_id($conn);

//Drop the connection
    $conn->close();
};
```

Edit:
I'm aware of the injection vulnerability.  The MySQL account only has SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE rights to the table. The end user must supply the password or submit will fail.  This is small app with limited user access at the moment.  MySQL escape strings will be implemented after current issue is resolved.

Edit 2:
Using Hobo Sapiens method does work in reporting an existing entry however a new (empty) row is still added to the table.  The record ID still auto-increments so what I get is id#300 - record, id#301 - blank,  id#302 - record.  Is this a result of the IGNORE in the INSERT statement?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: `$dupresult = 1` is an assignment, not a comparison. You also probably want to check `$conn->num_results($dupresult) > 0` or something like that. `$dupresult` will never equal 1 because it's MySQLi resource. Aside from that (and the gaping SQL injection), your logic seems fine.

Comment: Also, $dupresult must be a resource of some kind, it just means the query succeeded... oh my god this code is completely garbage, you have to review it completely.

Comment: possible duplicate of/related [why are assignments in conditions bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/317259/367456)

Comment: possible duplicate of/related [PHP, MySQLi - How do I count query result rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16257217/367456)

Comment: Why do (you think) you need to check first?

Comment: "oh my god this code is completely garbage, you have to review it completely" Thank you Sebas for the words of encouragement. I hope to someday achieve your level of expertise.

Comment: @Halcyon The code here is flawed as it introduces a possible race condition. This is not the way to test for uniqueness in a MySQl environment. The unique column should be marked as such (OP says it is), the `INSERT` performed with `IGNORE` and the result checked in `affected_rows`

Comment: @Haywood although Sebas' words are harsh he is not wrong. I certainly remember writing code like this when I first started out :)

Comment: @Halcyon while my code may not be ideal I think I'm doing well for a non-coder (not using deprecated methods for example). I appreciate constructive criticism and tend to treat comments such as Seba's as simply arrogant and unhelpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code creates a race condition if two people attempt to create the same ame at the same time and you're not handling the fallout properly.

If you have set the `SERVER_NAME` column to `UNIQUE` then you needn't check for the existence of a server name before you perform your `INSERT` as MySQL will do that for you. Use `INSERT IGNORE` ad check the number of affected rows after the query has executed to find out if it worked:

```
//Create connection to database using mysqli
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

//Set variables according to user input on previous form
$Server_Name = $_POST['Server_Name'];

//Define the INSERT statement with IGNORE keyword
    $stmt = "INSERT IGNORE INTO dcr_master (Server_Name, Description,..., ... , ... )";
    if ($conn->query($stmt) === false) {
        die("Database error:".$conn->error);
    }

// Check for success
    if ($conn->affected_rows == 0) {
        print "<br>Error! <p></p>";
        echo "" . $Server_Name . " already exists in the DCR";
        print "<p></p>Please check the Server Name and try again";
    } else {

//Success and return new id
        echo "<br><p></p>Record Added!<p></p>";
        echo "New id: " . $conn->insert_id;
    }
```

This is an **atomic** operation so no race condition, and it involves only one call to the database.

I recommend you use either the OOP style **or** the procedural style for `mysqli_*()` but don't mix them. Usual warnings about SQL injection apply.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
$row_cnt = $dupresult->num_rows;

if ($row_cnt > 0) {

   echo "There is a matching record";

}else {

   //insert into table

}
```

Comment: PHP reports an error when I added that code.  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 48 (the line containing $row_cnt = $dupresult->num_rows;)

Comment: This can happen if the select query fails. You get `false` instead of a `[MySQLi resource]`. You probably want to throw an `Exception` whenever a query fails.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
if($dupresult = 1)
```

will always return 1. You should first retrieve the first query result (if any), like so:

```
$row=$dupresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

and then compare the result against NULL:

```
if(!$row)
```

Comment: `$dupresult` is a MySQLi resource, when cast to a boolean it will always be `true`.

Comment: @Halcyon Unless it's `NULL`, where once casted will always be `false`. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: @Halcyon And since you don't even take the time to acknowledge your own errors, next time don't go around downvoting random posts if you don't even know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Halcyon I'm sorry, i looked into this again and found out that it was me being wrong. Both when i first wrote the answer, and still when i checked it again after it was downvoted, i was convinced that `$dupresult` was an array returned by something like `$result->fetch_assoc()`. And i'm aware that you explicitly pointed out that it was a MySQLi resource, but that unfortunately didn't turn on any light. My apologies

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not the one who gave you a downvote though. Have an upvote :D

Comment: @Halcyon Alright, well you could have, since i was wrong. I'm really sorry for what i said, again. Have a good one. Apologies again.